# Extend/Override Magento2 Template

Tags: magento2, module, extensions

I am trying to override some **Mageplaza 2 Blog Extension** template .phtml files

**(for this question lets focus on topmenu.html)**

Before you downvote me,
I read a tone of answers and tried implementing them, and nothing worked

I am a complete magento2 newbie whatever I know is mostly assumptions and whatever I experienced in my magento2 journey so far

**My Vendor Name: C2ghq**

**My theme Name: c2g**

What I tried so far and did**n't** work:

```
app/design/frontend/C2ghq/c2g/Mageplaza_BlogExtension/templates/html/topmenu.html
app/design/frontend/C2ghq/c2g/Mageplaza_Blogextension/templates/html/topmenu.html
app/design/frontend/C2ghq/c2g/Mageplaza_2BlogExtension/templates/html/topmenu.html
app/design/frontend/C2ghq/c2g/Mageplaza_Magento2BlogExtension/templates/html/topmenu.html
app/design/frontend/Mageplaza/c2g/Mageplaza_BlogExtension/templates/html/topmenu.html
```

---

In the vendor folder the extension has:

> /vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-blog-extension
>
> /vendor/mageplaza/module-core

What confuses me:

Magento's modules folder, has i.e. **module**-product, so the prefix is indeed "module", so if i want to override it, I do

```
app/design/frontend/C2ghq/c2g/Magento_Product/templates/...
```

But Mageplaza has **magento-2**-blog-extension, is it also considered a module?

---

***And finally:** What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
registration.php file:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mageplaza_Blog',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Have flush cache and delete all files from  var/view_procecessed ?

Comment: can you let me know which name defined under registration.php file?

Comment: Can u please share code of `vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-blog-extension\registration.php`

Comment: @Rakesh,  you are faster then me  :)

Comment: @AmitBera i have cache disabled, do i still need to delete all files?

Comment: @AmitBera registration.php code added! So i need to rename my first try to Mageplaza_Blog?  instead of Mageplaza_BlogExtension? xd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default, Any module with required mandatory **registration.php** file to run your module in site.

**registration.php** is entry point for each module.

If you are confused with module name, you just go to your module **registration.php** file.
like,

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mageplaza_Blog',
    __DIR__
);
```

In above file content, **Mageplaza_Blog** is your module name and based on this module name you can extend/override theme templates to your theme.

You need to do like below, Your module name is **Mageplaza_Blog**

```
app/design/frontend/C2ghq/c2g/Mageplaza_Blog/templates/html/topmenu.html
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess its also important to say in the answer where to find such information, every answer i ve read doenst mention registration.php, to a newbie like me its probably not so obvious to check it! If you can include it maybe the next one wont ask a new question. Maybe if possible add a more general answer. Though i accepted your answer as the correct one :D

Comment: @Alexandros, Kindly check i have updated my answer.

Comment: You are the best :D